# Jest: Trying to mock nested functions and redirects in jest, but no avail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

We are using a javascript framework(Not react) to render the ui.
main.js

```
function logout(){
    someObj.lock($('#container'), 'Logging out', true);
    document.location = app.context + `/${appName}/signout.action?name=${appName}`;
}

function action(event){
    switch(event.target){
        case 'user:logout':
            logout();
            break;
        case 'user:application':
            document.location = app.context + "/";
            break;
    }
}

module.exports = {
    action: action,
    logout: logout
}
```

main.js along with another js file renders a navbar and a dropdown. My intention is to check whether title, dropdown in the navbar is rendered. Also I 
am testing whether the browser redirect takes place in the right way.

action method takes an event object and based on its type, either performs signout('user:logout') or redirects to application page('user:application').

**tests**/main.js

```
import main from '../main';
describe("some title", () => {
    it("some behavior", () => {
        let event = {
            target: 'user:logout'
        }
        let app = {
            context: ''
        }
        let appName = 'Some app';
        main.logout = jest.fn();

        someObj = jest.fn();
        someObj.lock = jest.fn();

        document.location.assign = jest.fn();
        main.action(event);

        expect(main.logout).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(document.location.assign).toBeCalledWith(app.context + `/${appName}/signout.action?name=${appName}`);
    })
});
```

In the test file, I am trying to mock logout function. However it is executing someObj.lock function. someObj is not availabe to **tests**/main.js
and I am mocking it as well. I'm not sure whether I have to use spyOn instead. I'm using document.location.assign to test for browser redirects.
This test is not working and the terminal is displaying TypeError: Could not parse "/application name/signout.action?name=application name" as URL.

I have spent an entire day testing this feature but to no avail. I need some advice on the best way to test this feature.

Links explored: [Intercept navigation change with jest.js (or how to override and restore location.href)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169824/intercept-navigation-change-with-jest-js-or-how-to-override-and-restore-locatio)

jest documentation

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this? I have spent a lot of time reading documentation, SO articles but I am not able to make any progress.

Comment: It would help if you create a jsfiddle demo to reproduce the issue.