# How to simulate window.location change with react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, window.location

I'm migrating from `enzyme` to `react-testing-library`. I have a component called `<ScrollToTop/>` that just checks if `window.location` has changed since the last component update and scrolls to the top if it has.

`ScrollToTop.jsx`

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

export class UnwrappedScrollToTop extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (
      this.props.location !== prevProps.location &&
      !this.props.location.hash
    ) {
      window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default withRouter(UnwrappedScrollToTop);
```

My old enzyme test used `wrapper.setProps` to pass a new `location` and then tested whether `window.scrollTo` was called:

`ScrollToTop.test.js`

```
...
it("calls window.scrollTo (location changes, no hash)", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <UnwrappedScrollToTop children="" location={{ pathname: "dashboard" }} />
    );


    // pass different location prop to trigger componentDidUpdate
    wrapper.setProps({ location: { pathname: "library" } });

    // check to see if scrollToMock was called in componentDidUpdate
    expect(ScrollToMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      top: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  });
...
```

But I can't figure out how to translate this to `react-testing-library`, since I can't call `setProps` to pass a different location. How would I test this component?

Comment: You could spy on it? `spyOn(window, 'scrollTo')`

Comment: @evolutionxbox sure, but how do I create the condition of the changed `window.location`? I don't understand how to render a component, pass a new set of props to it programmatically, and then render it again using `react-testing-library`

Comment: I don't think you can, since the tests run in node, running `window.scrollTo` does nothing

Comment: @evolutionxbox so is there a different way to test a component like this then? or is it just not testable using this library?

Comment: An option is to mock react-router-dom's `withRouter`. Another option is to change the URL by assigning to location (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169824/intercept-navigation-change-with-jest-js-or-how-to-override-and-restore-locatio) and then call `rerender` from RTL. Or if you are only testing the unwrapped component, you can just `rerender`.

Comment: See https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#rerender

Comment: @JakubKotrs thank you!, if you post that as an answer i'll mark it as the accepted one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use the `rerender` function returned by `render`.

```
const {rerender} = render(<UnwrappedScrollToTop children="" location={{ pathname: "dashboard" }} />)

rerender(<UnwrappedScrollToTop children="" location={{ pathname: "library" }} />)

expect(ScrollToMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
});
```

Link to docs: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#rerender