# Mock window.location in TypeScript jest test

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I've got a piece of code the puts together a full URL for a redirection (something like this):

```
import { redirect } from './some-utils'

export const goToURL = () => {
    const url = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname
    redirect(url)
}
```

Now, I'm trying to write a TypeScript test that tests the URL string:

```
describe('my-test-file', () => {
    let originalWindowLocation
    const redirect = jest.fn()

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetAllMocks()
        originalWindowLocation = window.location
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        window.location = originalWindowLocation
    })

    it('test that redirection URL is correct', () => {
        delete window.location // can't do this because TS complains
        window.location = { origin: 'https://www.example.com', pathname: '/mypath' } // can't do this because TS complains

        goToURL()
        expect(redirect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        expect(redirect).toHaveBeeenCalledWith('https://www.example.com/mypath')
    })
})
```

However, I get two TypeScript errors. On the `delete` line:

> The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.

and on the new assignment of `window.location`:

> Type '{ origin: string; pathname: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Location | (string & Location)'. Type '{ origin: string; pathname: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string & Location'.
> Type '{ origin: string; pathname: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I tried fixing the first error by removing the `delete` statement and tried fixing the second error by adding `as Location` to the end of the assignment. Doing so fixes the TS errors but my test no longer passes. It uses the domain of my web app instead of the example one in my test.

Can anyone help me fix up my TS errors while ensuring that my tests pass?

Edit:

If I try `window.location = 'https://www.example.com/mypath'`, my test still does not pass and I still get a TS error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Location | (string & Location)'

If I try `window.location.href = 'https://www.example.com/mypath'`, the TS errors go away but the test does not pass.

If I try `window.location.assign(https://www.example.com/mypath')`, the TS errors go away but the test does not pass.

Comment: [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) is _read-only_, but you can assign a `string` to it.

Comment: So I've tried `window.location = 'https://www.example.com/mypath'` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73964371/mock-window-location-in-typescript-jest-test?noredirect=1#comment130597517_73964371) That's correct. You can also assign a string to `window.location.href` (which will work fine in TS).

Comment: Yes, the `href` works. However, the code I'm responsible for testing constructs a URL by appending `window.location.origin` with `window.location.pathname` neither of which are mocked or set by setting `href` so therefore my test still fails.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73964371/mock-window-location-in-typescript-jest-test?noredirect=1#comment130597640_73964371) That may be the case, but you haven't shown any code which invokes `redirect` in a test, so why would you expect the test to pass? Please update the question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Updated post with more detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intercept navigation change with jest.js (or how to override and restore location.href)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169824/intercept-navigation-change-with-jest-js-or-how-to-override-and-restore-locatio)

Comment: Not entirely. The ultimate issue is NOT the redirect or what is assigned to window.location but the app code is constructing the URL in the way that I showed and I'm asking if there's a way to mock that out or if I need to change it to a better URL construction.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73964371/mock-window-location-in-typescript-jest-test?noredirect=1#comment130598058_73964371) You're going to have to mock all or some of `window.location` if you want to intercept and test navigation attempts which use that object. Re: construction: that's what the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) class is for: `const urlString = new URL(pathname, origin).href`

Comment: Hm...an example of how I would mock out the `origin` and `pathname` of `window.location` that makes TypeScript happy is what I need.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73964371/mock-window-location-in-typescript-jest-test?noredirect=1#comment130598262_73964371) It's close to the `URL` class already. Just mock it using an instance of that if you don't use non-URL methods in your code.

Comment: Ah! Okay, yes I think that is what I need. Thank you! If you want to write up an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are only using a subset of the [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) API that's also available on an instance of [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) (e.g. `window.location.href = "https://domain.tld/pathname"`), then you can manually mock (replace) that property on `window` during your tests:

```ts
describe('description', () => {
  let originalWindowLocation = window.location;

  beforeEach(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      value: new URL(window.location.href),
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      value: originalWindowLocation,
    });
  });

  it('test that redirection URL is correct', () => {
    const expectedUrl = 'https://www.example.com/mypath';
    window.location.href = expectedUrl;
    expect(window.location.href).toBe(expectedUrl);
  });
});
```

---

I intentionally did not address the other aspects of your code because it's not what you asked about, but if you want to mock a function invocation (e.g. `redirect`) in a closure (e.g. `goToURL`) from an external module, you'll need to mock that function. See [mocking modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules) and [mocking partials](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials) in the Jest documentation.

Comment: `originalWindowLocation` is just a reference to `window.location`, so when you override it, the value of `originalWindowLocation` also updates, therefore it doesn't do anything...

Comment: Thanks for the solution, can you or some expound upon why you need to do ```Object.defineProperty``` in order for this to work?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73964371/mock-window-location-in-typescript-jest-test/73965890?noredirect=1#comment135211663_73965890) @AdamDunmars [Because it’s a read-only property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `delete` since this is a *read-only* property.

MDN says you can change the origin and the pathname with `location.replace()`. Here's [an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#example_3)

```
location.replace('http://example.com/my-path');
```

Answer (score -2):

### Mock window.location.assign

This is the way I've done it.

It sure is convenient to simply cram a new string into `window.location` or `window.location.href`, but that is not amenable to testing.

**Rule 0 of testing code**: the code must be written such that it *can* be tested.

So, switch to `window.location.assign(url)` in your app code.

But, to verify that the app really did attempt to change the URL, you must spy on the assign method during the test, like so:

```js
let assignSpy = jest.spyOn(window.location, 'assign')

// ...arrange, act

expect(assignSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith( theUrlYouExpect )
```

Your test can't simply inspect the current `window.location` or `window.location.href`. The entire purpose of switching to the `assign` method is because we can spy on methods. That is, we switched from a technique that works but is untestable, to a different technique that has the same effect and is testable.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your answer. I think my main issue is the construction of the url to begin with so while I can do `window.location.assign`, it is the `url` itself that is being constructed with `origin` and `pathname` but I'm unsure how to change it or how to mock it so it can be tested.

Comment: Attempting to create the spy on `window.location.assign` yields the following error: >  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'assign' of object '[object Location]'

      at Object.restore (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:786:35)
          at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)